# There is a function to use pattern matching (using regular expressions) in C++?

Tags: c++, regex, string

There is a simple C++ method to use pattern matching on strings? The code should sound like this:

```
if (regexpcmp("l?nole*[0-9]", "linoleum1")) {
  //we have a match!
} else {
   //no match 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in the core language. Use Boost.Regex or an external library like `pcre`. In a unix environment you almost certainly have access to the BSD regular expression tools (`regcomp`, `regerror`, `regexec`, `regfree`) which are c-like rather than c++-like but do work.

Comment: I'm in *nix enviroinment so i'll use the BSD regular expression tools like the example at the bottom of this page
http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/regcomp.html

Answer (score 11):

Did you already look at [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/)?

```
const boost::regex e("l?nole*[0-9]");
if (regex_match("linoleum1", e)) {
  //we have a match!
} else {
  //no match 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take boost.regex friend. if you are not allowed to use boost (sadly, there are still companies doing this), you could look into `pcrecpp`, which is a C++ binding developed by google for the famous [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) library.

Comment: lol. If you're not allowed to use a 3rd party library, then you just  use a 3rd party library :-) Such companies are stupid.

Comment: What, like Google for instance? Its published coding standard allows use of only a few specific things from Boost. They must be stupid like a multi-billionaire fox ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A standard regex library (that is based on boost::regex) is available in the TR1 namespace if you use lasts versions of the most used compilers : std::tr1::regex.