# is it possible to use regex in c++?

Tags: c++, c, regex

Duplicate of: [There is a function to use pattern matching (using regular expressions) in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329517/there-is-a-function-to-use-pattern-matching-using-regular-expressions-in-c)

I'm not sure where one would use it... are there any parser-type functions that take some regex as an argument or something? I just found out that my editor will highlight a line after / as "regex" for C/C++ syntax which I thought was weird...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the vanilla C++ language there is no support for regular expressions.  However there are several libraries available that support Regex's.  Boost is a popular one.

Check out Boost's Regex implementation.

- http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2006/04/06/boostregex.html
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax.html

Comment: Until TR1 is supported by compilers.

Answer (score 8):

[PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) is the de-facto standard regex library for C (and it also works in C++).

(What your editor is doing I don't know.  Using a library like PCRE or any of the others suggested doesn't change the syntax of C - your regex definitions will always be held in strings.)

Answer (score 2):

See: [There is a function to use pattern matching (using regular expressions) in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329517/there-is-a-function-to-use-pattern-matching-using-regular-expressions-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Regular Expressions are part of the C++ standard library extension defined in TR1 ([see Chapter 7 in Documentation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1836.pdf)). The [dinkumware library](http://www.dinkumware.com) i.e has implemented the regEx extensions. I dont know about other implementations.

The extensions are simple and straight forward to use.

Answer (score 1):

[Boost.Xpressive](http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/libs/xpressive/doc/html/index.html) allows you to write regexs as strings (like in [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)) or statically with expression templates. It is similar to [Boost.Spirit](http://spirit.sourceforge.net/) for grammars.

For example, these two are equivalent:

```
sregex rex1 = sregex::compile("(\\w+) (\\w+)!"); //normal string based way
sregex rex2 = (s1= +_w) >> ' ' >> (s2= +_w) >> '!'; //expression template way
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, Qt has a [QRegExp](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qregexp.html) that can do regular expression matching.
This is usually good if you need a small regexp for a remote feature in your grand Qt application. For anything more serious, PCRE is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

No, C++ does not have, and is not going to get, regexes using the /.../ syntax used in some languages. Your editor is wrong.

As all the other answers show, regex libraries for C++ do exist (And one is scheduled for inclusion in C++0x), but they process strings, delimited by ", not slashes, so they are not the reason for your editor's behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you use visual studio and portability is not a major issue, you can get results pretty quickly (no downloads, no installations) with a cute ATL facility called [CAtlRegExp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3zs4axe(VS.80).aspx).    It contains full and efficient RegEx parsing and matching ([online sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2611dd(VS.80).aspx)). Haven't compared its performance to BOOST, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can perform a regex in C++ without using some third-party library. Qt and Gtk+/Gtkmm both come with these. Visual C++ 2008 also comes with this ability.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Visual Studio you can use Greta (search greta regex) but i think it's a bit slower than boost. It's really easy to use though.