# Does C or C++ have a standard regex library?

Tags: c++, c, regex, standard-library

Does it? If yes, where can I get the documentation for it... if not, then which would be the best alternative?

Comment: Near-duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181624, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923500 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815429.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329517/there-is-a-function-to-use-pattern-matching-using-regular-expressions-in-c

Comment: BTW: you could have had a wealth of information faster and easier by searching: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c+c%2B%2B+regex+standard

Answer (score 31, accepted):

C++11 now finally does have a [standard regex library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Regular_expressions) - std::regex.

If you do not have access to a C++11 implementation, a good alternative could be [boost regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).  It isn't completely equivalent to std::regex (e.g. [the "empty()" method is not in the std::regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799705/boostregex-vs-stdregex-cant-find-empty-method)) but it's a very mature regex implementation for C++ none the less.

Comment: This answer is dated, as of 2012 the answer is now Yes, C++ has a standard regex library, mandated by C++11, under the header "regex"

Comment: @Clairvoire - I've decided to edit / update my answer to the changes since late 2009, thanks for the heads-up on this outdated answer.

Comment: The difference is also the c++ standard does not support named subgroups, that is naming parts of regular expressions so that later you can get them by name.

Answer (score 8):

Under UNIX-like systems you can use [POSIX regex functions](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html).

Answer (score 6):

The Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Feature Pack 1 (now rolled into the Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1) contains a implementation of the 'official' TR1 reg ex types. Knock yourself out :-)

Answer (score 5):

Check the [boost regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) library. It should become part of the standard with C++0x.

Answer (score 4):

If by *standard* you mean bundled with compiler, then not. But most of the other languages that bundle regex extension use pretty standard `c` implementations. E.g. [PCRE - Perl Compatible Regular Expression](http://pcre.org/) and C libraries have POSIX regex support (see [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regex)).

Answer (score 2):

Regular Expressions are part of the C++ extension TR1. Dinkumware, visual studio and others already have implemented this.
See

[Quick Start for C++ TR1 Regular Expressions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/TR1Regex.aspx)

[Visual C++ 2008 Feature Pack](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=2&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fdownloads%2Fdetails.aspx%3FFamilyId%3DD466226B-8DAB-445F-A7B4-448B326C48E7&ei=i1quSo0OiJv8BoaW6K8G&rct=j&q=regex+tr1+visual+studio&usg=AFQjCNEJBR1VCa3sblSRRAaIFcPNTBexdw)

Answer (score 1):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/), from Trolltech, also has a regex implementation which I find very easy to use. However, if you are not planning of using Qt for anything else I would use Boost.Regex as you probably would be good off using Boost for other purposes as well.

Answer (score 1):

The standard ISO/IEC 14882:2011 Programming Language C++ describes a regex class as part of C++'s library, which is heavily influenced by the mature Boost library.

Curiously, as of January 2013, compilers' compliance with this standard is still spotty, e.g. the GNU compiler suite's popular C++ compiler does not support/comply with this part of the standard.

For that reason, it's best to use Boost at this point in time until compiler support reaches compliance.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for [PCRE - Perl Compatible Regular Expression](http://www.pcre.org/) , I remembered using [Mircosoft's GRETA](http://cplus.about.com/b/2007/04/11/greta-a-free-regular-expression-library-for-visual-c.htm) as well.