# boost::regex vs std::regex - can't find empty() method?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, c++11, std

Replacing `boost::regex` with `std::regex` since we are using gcc 4.6 in the company I ran into an issue with [`empty ()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/basic_regex.html#boost_regex.basic_regex.empty) method of that class - it basically didn't make it from `boost::regex` into `std::regex` class. I am not sure whether this is a gcc's issue or this method didn't make it into C++11 standard at all, but that piece of code was heavily depending on this feature. So the question is - is there a way in C++11 `std::regex` to check if expression was ever set or I should stick to `boost::regex` for the rest of my life?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Really? I thought it is. It is in MSVC, wikipedia mentions it as well here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Regular_expressions
So it didn't finally make it into the standard last minute?

Comment: @VladLazarenko I'm looking at N3290 and can't find it.

Comment: @pmr: ... but it was in TR1.. Do you know what the heck is going on?

Comment: "or I should stick to boost::regex for the rest of my life? " ... if the use of `empty()` isn't completely sprinkled all over your project, you might be able to quite easily refactor the code using it to use a combination of the regexp and a `boost::optional` (or some variant of this feature)

Comment: @Martin: That's what I though, too. But I don't really want to refactor for the sake of refactoring. Replacing is one thing, but spending time refactoring for no good reason is another :)

Comment: @Vlad: You're not refactoring for the sake of refactoring. You're refactoring because you "want" to use std::regex and it isn't fully compatible with boost:regex.

Comment: No, the goal is to profit, not to use std::regex, actually. I tried to replace it with `std` because I thought it won't hurt to get less dependencies on Boost. But thing didn't work out, and it is not really worth it to spend time on this. Just got curious about what the hell those guys at committee thought before getting rid of `empty ()`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`empty()` got removed from `std::regex` a long time ago.  [N1507](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1507.htm) (2003-09-16) was the original paper to suggest its removal (search for "What is an invalid/empty regular expression?").  This issue was directed at what then was `std::tr1:regex`.  It was recorded in the LWG tr1 issues lists as issue 7.28 and contained the following resolution:

> Discussed at Kona. The LWG agrees that the default constructor should
> be equivalent to construction from an empty string. Leaving this open
> for now partly because we need wording expressing that, and partly
> because it’s not clear that there’s any point to having the `empty()`
> member function in the first place.

[N1711](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1711.pdf) (2004-11-04) was the first TR1 draft to lack `basic_regex::empty()`.  From there it got imported from TR1 into C++11 with no further discussion.