# Reading XML file in openCV

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

I have an .xml file with the following contents:

```
<annotation>
    <filename>action0005.jpg</filename>
    <originalfile>26467307_0b0731a09b.jpg</originalfile>
    <folder>Willow-actions</folder>
    <source>
        <annotation>Willow-actions</annotation>
        <database>Willow-actions</database>
        <image>flickr</image>
        <flickrid>26467307</flickrid>
    </source>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <size>
        <width>400</width>
        <height>266</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <object>
        <name>person</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>49</xmin>
            <ymin>3</ymin>
            <xmax>272</xmax>
            <ymax>266</ymax>
        </bndbox>
        <pose>Frontal</pose>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <truncated>1</truncated>
        <occluded>1</occluded>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

My question is, how do i read and store only the xmin, ymin, xmax and ymax values in the < bndbox > < / bndbox > ?
From the OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html), probably i have to use the FileNodeIterator ? Or is there a simple way to do this ?

Simply doing:

```
 Mat bndBox;

    FileStorage fs("action0773.jpg", FileStorage::READ);
    fs["bndbox"] >> bndBox;

    cout << bndBox << endl;
```

won't store the values 49, 3, 272 and 266 in the Mat structure.

Comment: is that really *all* of your xml file ? or are there several annotations in it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185365/reading-parts-of-a-line-getline

Comment: @berak thanks for the reply. I've downloaded the willow action dataset here: http://www.di.ens.fr/willow/research/stillactions/. In that dataset they have 911 image (.jpg) and annotation (.xml) files. The annotation i posted above is just one of the .xml file.

Comment: This is still unsolved